# Approximating the initial value problem $x'(t)=\sqrt{|x(t)|}, x(0)=0$ by solutions of ODEs with smooth right hand side

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $$x'(t) = \sqrt{|x(t)|}, \ x(0) = 0.$$ Note that the right hand side is not Lipschitz at $x=0$. There are infinitely many solutions to this, e.g. $x_0\equiv 0$ and for any $r > 0$, $$x_r(t) = \begin{cases} 0 &t\leq r,\\  \frac{1}{4} (t - r)^2 & t > r.\end{cases}$$ My question is: If we pick one of these solutions, call it $x$, can we find a $C^0_{loc}$-approximation of $f(x):=\sqrt{|x|}$ by $C^{\infty}$-functions $f_{\varepsilon}(x)$ such that the solutions of an appropriate initial value problem (which are then necessarily unique) for the ODEs $x_{\varepsilon}'(t) = f_{\varepsilon}(x_{\varepsilon}(t))$ converge to $x$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Comment: i am no expert but you might be interested in looking up these notes of Camilo de Lellis talking about the work of Ambrosio and Diperna-Lions https://smf.emath.fr/download/pdf/42674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous, but not smooth idea. Restrict the derivative and thus get a finite Lipschitz constant via $f_ε(x)=\sqrt{\max(ε,|x|)}$. This will initially grow as $\sqrtε·t$ until at $t=\sqrtε$ the level $ε$ is reached and the solution continues with the quadratic. This will not converge to the zero segment on $[0,r]$.

So in a second try, set $f_ε(x)=\sqrt{\max(ε,|x|)}-c\sqrtε$, $c\in (0,1)$. The intercept of $(1-c)\sqrtε·t=ε$ is at $\frac{\sqrtε}{1-c}$. So if this is set to $r$, then $1-c=\frac{\sqrtε}r$, so that in total
$$
f_ε(x)=\sqrt{\max(ε,|x|)}-\sqrtε+\frac{ε}r.
$$

I'm quite optimistic that smooth variants, for instance based on $|x|\approx\sqrt{ε^2+x^2}$, could be constructed in a similar fashion.