# Approximating a given solution of an IVP with continuous RHS by solutions of IVPs with smooth RHS

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem (IVP) $$x'(t) = f(x(t)),\quad x(t_0) = x_0,$$ where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function (we explicitly do not require $f$ to be Lipschitz anywhere, so the above IVP will in general have many solutions). Let $x:(t_0-\delta, t_0 + \delta) \to \mathbb{R}$ be some solution of this IVP. My question is the following: Can we now, given this data, construct smooth functions $f_{\varepsilon}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{\varepsilon} \to f$ locally uniformly as $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ and such that the (necessarily unique) solutions $x_{\varepsilon}$ of some appropriate initial value problem $$x_{\varepsilon}'(t) = f_{\varepsilon}(x_{\varepsilon}(t)),\ x_{\varepsilon}(t_0) = x_{\varepsilon 0},$$ where $x_{\varepsilon 0} \to x_0$, converge to $x$ (say, locally uniformly)?

I am grateful for any ideas of how such $f_{\varepsilon}$ can be constructed out of $f$ and $x$ (or any ideas for counterexamples to this claim).

(Comments:

1. This question is a sort of converse of Thm. 3.2 in Ch.2 of Hartman's ODE book, 2nd ed., which says that for a given locally uniform smooth approximation $f_{\varepsilon}$, a sequence of solutions of $f_{\varepsilon}$-IVPs converges to a solution of the limit $f$-IVP.
2. Note that for right hand sides $f$ that are only non-Lipschitz in isolated points, such as $f=\sqrt{|.|}$, one can construct such smooth approximations by changing $f$ only near such a non-Lipschitz point, see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034163/approximating-the-initial-value-problem-xt-sqrtxt-x0-0-by-solutio). But it is unclear to me how to generalize this to more complicated $f$. In the worst case, $f$ may be nowhere locally Lipschitz, such as the Weierstrass function.)

EDIT 1: If $x_0$ isn't an equilibrium point, i.e. if $f(x_0) \neq 0$, then one can show that the above IVP has a unique solution $x$. So in that case, for any $C^{\infty}$-approximation $f_{\varepsilon}$ and any sequence of initial values $x_{\varepsilon 0} \to x_0$, the solutions $x_{\varepsilon}$ will necessarily converge to $x$. Hence we may assume that $f(x_0) = 0$ above, if that helps.